# How to tap master page in Master Detail page in Xamarin forms UI Test?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I have given AutomationId , it is not working for master page,but its detail page is working fine.How to tap the Hamburger icon of Master Detail Page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the reference to the hamburger icon with this query:

```
x => x.Class("ImageButton").Marked("OK");
```

A good example of this in use is the Evolve 2016 app by Xamarin. Take a look at the code line 93 [here](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-conference/blob/master/src/Conference.UITests/BasePage.cs#L93).

Comment: Can you also tell me how to move back to the Previous Page using navigation bar back button in Xamarin forms Unit testing

Comment: This is working. Important - Check name your class (with repl). I have "AppCompatImageButton" name.

Comment: @FetFrumos Good observation, didn't think of that.